# Linking one xml to another xml using ImageButton in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: eclipse, adt

I am new to Android App Development and i am using Eclipse ADT. Basically I made my Home page for my app and my problem is I don't know how to link one xml file to another xml file. What i want to happen is, When I click the "Payment" on my homepage (Please refer to the screenshot..) I want it to redirect to another page (specifically on the 2nd screenshot). Please help me and I am having a hard time. I'm starting from scratch. :(( The "Payment" Button is an IMAGEBUTTON.

Btw. The homepages xml name is activity_main.xml and i want to redirect it to payvia.xml (Blank XML file). I just want to know how to do it. I know theres something to edit on the MainActivity.java and in the AndroidManifest.xml

Please I need your expert advices.

I cant attach screenshots because i lack reputation pts.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man. You have to make two activity. One for your activity_main.xml and one for your payvia.xml . And after you have made the activity than you define your button on your main activity and set a Intent and say when you click the button then open a new intentand that new intent will be the second activity.  I hope you have solved it till now. otherwise tell me again. Anyway it is the basic thing of building apps on eclipse.